# Copiar determinado número de arquivos em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automatização

Olá, tudo bem?

Estou iniciando na programação, estou tentando automatizar algumas tarefas no meu ambiente de trabalho e tenho a seguinte necessidade:

Efetuar a cópia de x arquivos (x será fornecido pelo user) para outro diretório... fiz algumas pesquisas e desenvolvi algo próximo a isso:

```
import shutil
import os
origem = r"C:/Copiador/de/"
destino = r"C:/Copiador/para/"
lista = os.listdir(origem)
x = 0 
num_files = 20 #aqui seria o valor que o user iria fornecer
while x < num_files:
    origemtotal = origem + lista[x]
    destinototal = destino + lista[x] 
    shutil.move(origemtotal, destinototal)       
    print(x, '-', lista[x]) 
    x +=1;
```

A questão é que, quando o num_files é maior que o número de arquivos na origem, o programa retorna erro :

IndexError: list index out of range

Eu acredito que é até esperado, pois ele não achou o índice que procurava pra efetuar a cópia...
Porém não consegui pensar em um modo de caso o num_files seja maior que a quantidade de arquivos na origem, ele efetuar a cópia da quantidade de arquivos na origem e finalizar a execução.

Talvez eu esteja errando em algo básico que não esteja vendo... Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Seria interessante você validar se esse `num_files` é maior que a quantidade de arquivos. Caso sim, o `num_files` recebe o número real de arquivos na origem.

Comment: Guto, 
Obrigado pela ajuda, funcionou tranquilamente...

        if lista_len < num_files:
            num_files = lista_len
        else:
            pass

Eu só adicionei isso antes do While e agora funcionou sem problemas.

Comment: Coloquei como resposta. Se puder aceitar eu agradeço.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seria interessante você validar se esse `num_files` é maior que a quantidade de arquivos. Caso sim, o `num_files` recebe a quantidade real de arquivos na origem.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

```py
import shutil
import os
origem = r"C:/Copiador/de"
destino = r"C:/Copiador/para/"
lista = os.listdir(origem)
num_files = 5 #aqui seria o valor que o user iria fornecer
if len(lista) < num_files:
    num_files = len(lista)

print(num_files)

# loop de cópia
```